# Keep background image position static even though percentages are used

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

To preface this, I'm not sure if this is even possible, but I am trying to have it done (perhaps using calc(), somehow?)

Anyhow, I have a div that is of variable size (changes on hover), and it does a transition while changing size. In order to keep this transition smooth, I need the background image of the div to not move when the div is resized.

Problem is, I have the background image positioned using percentages (which I have to stick to). So I'm not sure if something can be done to use the initial value obtained from the percentage, and then stick to that value.

[image: Before hovering]

[image: After hovering]

```
.expandedcard {
    background-size: auto 90% !important;
    background-position: 90% 110% !important;
}
```

So, to reiterate, the 90% is (internally, I guess) converted to a pixel value. I want to keep said pixel value static after the initial loading of the page, and not change it to 90% of the now smaller div, in order to keep my expanding transition smooth.

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: I understand your question, however you need to provide a minimal reproducible example. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Hey, my bad, thanks. I managed to come up with a workaround, anyway, so I'll just be posting that in a bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had to use javascript to handle stuff dynamically.

```
function adjustPosition(item, bp, sizer) {
    if (bp == "xxl") {
        if (window.matchMedia("(min-width: 1400px)").matches) {
            var aspectRatio = $(sizer).width() / $(sizer).height();
            var bgImageHeight = $(item).height() * 0.9;
            var bgImageWidth = bgImageHeight * aspectRatio;
            var pxW = ($(item).width() - bgImageWidth) - (0.1 * $(item).width());
            $("head").append('<style type="text/css">' + item + ' {background-position:' + pxW + 'px 110% !important;}</style>');
        }
    }
}
```

What this does is, it dynamically calculates the pixel position that would represent the 90% position, and adds it to the css of the page. I also used elements I called "sizers", which are hidden versions of the images that I'd use to get the width/height of the image and therefore the aspect ratio.

Pretty stupid solution, to be honest, but it's what I could think of. I'm sure there's a better way to do this.